# liberty profile configuration issue (log4j2)

Tags: java, log4j2, jvm-arguments, websphere-liberty

I can successfully set up log4j logging by setting up the following line within my jvm.options file:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=C:/eclipse/runtime/usr/servers/tmpServer/log4j2.xml
```

However, I want to change this, so the path is not hard coded.

I was hoping this would work:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=${server.config.dir}/log4j2.xml
```

But it does not. Any ideas why not?

I'm using liberty profile, and my log4j2.xml file is in the same directory as the jvm.options file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell and variable expansion are not supported in `jvm.options` - check this page [Customizing the Liberty profile environment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_admin_customvars.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-3-11-0-3-2-0&lang=en) - however `server.config.dir` is default working directory so setting: `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=./log4j2.xml` should work.